# Error: Program type already present: class

Tags: java, android, android-gradle

Почему я получаю такую ошибку. Насколько я знаю здесь дело с gradle. Как исправить ошибку? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: a]

Comment: покажите класс AdapterOffice :)

Comment: у вас похоже 2 класса с одним и тем же именем

Comment: В проекте один такой класс. Если удалить adapterOffice, в ошибке будет написан просто другой класс.